# OpenOffice 3.3.0 menu entry "Send -> Document as e-mail" does not work with Zarafa Web-Client

Tags: email, openoffice

We have a Windows XP SP3 (German) with OpenOffice 3.3.0 installed and use Zarafa as Groupware. We modified the registry in order to set Zarafa WebAccess (Browser -> website) as the default mail client. Furthermore the internet settings of Windows contain "Zarafa WebAccess" as default mail client.

In most cases, this works perfectly. When clicking on mail links in the browser or an OpenOffice document, Zarafa WebAccess pops up and provides the mask for sending out a new mail via the browser. So far, so good.

Now there are some special cases. For example, OpenOffice provides an additional menu entry:
File -> send -> Document as e-mail

When selecting this menu entry, OpenOffice throws me an error:
  "OpenOffice.org was not able to find a working mail configuration."
  (Translated from German to English.)

Browsing the OpenOffice bug tracker and forums I found out, that since OpenOffice 2.2 for Windows, you are no longer able to select a default mail client in the OpenOffice settings. Instead OpenOffice uses the system defaults.

We do have the same problem with some other applications, such as the Adobe Acrobat Reader.
One idea was that the previously deinstalled mail client Thunderbird still hangs around in the registry and therefore still is called by third party applications. As it turned out, the programm "Thunderbird" was not found in the registry, which means that third party applications shouldn't be aware of the old mail client which is no longer installed.

Do you have any idea what goes wrong here? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Fyi: Since nobody seems to able to solve this (including me :-)), I have contacted the Zarafa community and support. Maybe they know something.. ofc I will update my question accordingly later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, replying to my own question is according the rules of this website.
Unfortunately, one is not able to enhance the Zarafa WebAccess to a full mail client, where a "full mail client" is a third party application such as Thunderbird or Outlook. No matter how good you modify the Windows registry, some applications still won't map their special function "send as mail" to the default mail client.

As long as those clients do not possess a configuration possibility for the special functions, you can't use Zarafa WebAccess for them.

However, Zarafa provides a plugin for OpenOffice and it might be worth the try:
  http://download.zarafa.com/community/final/Plugins

Furthermore Zarafa will release a new version of the WebAccess soon which is called WebApp. WebApp might be better in terms of integration to the desktop and will allow enhancements through plugins. But this is more a long term project.